# How to read URL Body in PUT of WCF rest service?

Tags: .net, wcf, json.net, wcf-rest

I am new to WCF rest services . I am trying to implement PUT method which will get JSON input from client

Consider this as my url body:

```
{"73":"456212c5-149c-4f04-a41d-47eeb8feee01","74":"4825c4be-2f58-4021-88b1-a5dcd17079b5"}
```

I have implemented following code

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/ListOfAlerts", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    void CloseAlert(String alertIDsToClose);
```

IN Service:

```
SCOM_ConnectionSettings();
        Guid alertId = Guid.Empty;
        //StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(alertIDsToClose);
        //streamReader.
        Dictionary<string, string> alertIDs = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(alertIDsToClose);
        #region test
        //String str = WebOperationContext.Current.IncomingRequest.Accept.ToString();

        //StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(alertIDs);
        //String res = reader.ReadToEnd();

        //NameValueCollection coll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(res);

        //foreach(string alertID in alertIDs)
        //{
        #endregion
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> alertID in alertIDs)
        {
            alertId = new Guid(alertID.Value);
        }

        MonitoringAlert monitoringAlert = mgGroup.GetMonitoringAlert(alertId);


        ReadOnlyCollection<MonitoringAlertResolutionState> alertStates = mgGroup.GetMonitoringAlertResolutionStates();

        MonitoringAlertResolutionState closedState = null;
        foreach (MonitoringAlertResolutionState thisState in alertStates)
        {
            if (thisState.Name == "Closed")
            {
                closedState = thisState;
            }
        }

        if (monitoringAlert.ResolutionState != closedState.ResolutionState)
        {
            monitoringAlert.ResolutionState = closedState.ResolutionState;
            string comment = "closing availability alert";
            monitoringAlert.Update(comment);
        }

    }
```

How  i can specify that  json data is available in body not in url .How come my function come to to read data from Body.Am i in correct track?

Please suggest me...

Comment: I didn't understand exactly your issue here... if you trying to send that json as parameter, you don't need to convert or split the values, you can use a class, or even for the json you posted, you should receive a string pair in your method, something like this: CloseAlert(Dictionary<string,string> obj)

Comment: If i am getting it as a body how i should take .how cum my function knows that it should take from body not from path value/request parameters.I wanted to specify any attribute ?Can you give any example .

Comment: Your function came to know the Body data because of operation type performed. if HTTP method is POST/PUT then client need to upload the data in body of the request to the Url. WCF handles it internally you don't need to worry about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would real simple if you use an array of object instead of comma separated JSON items. Use a DataContract as parameter in the `CloseAlerts`.

```
[DataContract]
public class Alert
{
    [DataMember( Name = "Id",IsRequired = false)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "Guid", IsRequired = false)]
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
}
```

Now method signature would be:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, UriTemplate = "/ListOfAlerts", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string CloseAlert(Alert[] alertIDsToClose);
```

That's it. Here's how you can test it:

```
Alert[] alerts = new [] { 
    new Alert {Id =1, guid = Guid.NewGuid()}, 
    new Alert {Id =2, guid = Guid.NewGuid()}
};

// Serialize with Json.net to keep more generalized
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(alerts, typeof(Alert[]), new JsonSerializerSettings());

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();       
webClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";            
webClient.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;

webClient.UploadString(baseAddress + "/ListOfAlerts", "POST", data);
```